# Perl Win32::OLE word merging two doc files

Tags: perl

I'm trying to merge two document into new doc file but I'm getting error in following code.

```
    use strict;
    use Win32::OLE;
    use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';

    $meta_file_path = "D:\\copyfrom.doc";
    $main_file_path = "D:\\copyto.doc";

    my $x = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') ;
    my $word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit; } );
    my $doc = $word->Documents->open($meta_file_path) or die $!;

        my $doc = $word->Documents->Open($meta_file_path) or die $!;
$word->ActiveDocument->Content;
$word->ActiveDocument->Select();
$word->Selection->Copy();
$doc->Close;
my $doc2 = $word->Documents->Open($main_file_path) or die $!;       
$word->ActiveDocument->Content->Paste();
$word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs('D:\\outdoc.doc');
$doc2->Close;       
exit;
```

Error is :

```
Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020011: "Does not support a collection"
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "" at D:/merge.pl line 12.
Can't call method "Content" on an undefined value at D:/merge.pl line 12.
```

I got a code from [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=213797) which give me desire output but their is one problem in format, copyfrom.doc has tables and text with different alignment and font family from copyto.doc.

Comment: [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579719/how-to-merge-two-doc-files-into-new-doc-file) you have already asked.

Comment: @serenesat yes but previous problem doesn't explain problem thats why I add another question Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to use the current document as part of the Documents collection, while it's actually part of the Word application object.
I don't have the means to test the code here, but try changing

```
$doc->ActiveDocument
```

to

```
$word->ActiveDocument
```

Comment: I made changes but still not get the correct output. Changing in $word makes it error free but it not merge two document it just saveas the 1st document...plz guide

Comment: If the solution solved your error, you should mark it as an answer. As to the fact that nothing is copied to the output file, try using SelectAll instead of Select.